# Global int variable objective c

Tags: objective-c, global

I want to declare a static int variable in one class and have access to it in every other class. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Global Variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601341/iphone-global-variable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no static class variables in Objective C. You can create it as a file-scope static variable in the class' implementation file and provide static setter and getter methods in the class.

Or you can make it an old-school global, with an `extern` declaration in the .h file. The former approach is more flexible - you can add extra checks in the setter method, for example, the latter is less typing, and avoids the method call overhead.

Comment: Can I use extern in more than one class to get access to the variable? I have at least 4 classes I want to be able to access it.

Comment: Sure. Either place the `extern int myvar;` declaration in each file where the variable is needed, or place it into an .h file and #import the .h file where needed.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some ways you could try

- Declaring the global variables in appdelegate
- Creating a singleton class and putting the global variables
  there.

---

### Using appdelegate

appdelegate is also a kind of singleton class

**Function definition:**

```
-(NSString*)ReadAppDelegateInstanceVariable:(NSString*)InstVar 
{
AppDelegate *appDel=(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
return [appDel valueForKey:InstVar];
}
```

**Function Calling:**

```
[self ReadAppDelegateInstanceVariable:@"someInstanceVariableName"];
```

---

### Using your own singleton class

Only one instance of class can exist.

**Sample singleton declaration:**

```
@interface SigletonClass : NSObject
{
  //declare instance variable
}
+ (id)sharedSingletonClass;
@end
```

**Sample singleton implementation:**

**Approach 1:** Using GCD

```
@implementation SigletonClass

+ (id)sharedSingletonClass {

    static SigletonClass *sharedClass = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;//The way we ensure that it’s only created once is by using the dispatch_once method from Grand Central Dispatch (GCD).

   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
     sharedClass = [[self alloc] init];
  });

    return sharedClass;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
     //init instance variable        
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**Approach 2:** Without using GCD

```
@implementation SigletonClass

+ (id)sharedSingletonClass {

    static SigletonClass *sharedClass = nil;

    @synchronized(self) {//To safeguard threading issues

        if (sharedClass == nil)
            sharedClass = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedClass;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
     //init instance variable        
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**Function definition:**

```
-(NSString*)ReadSingleTonInstanceVariable:(NSString*)InstVar 
{
   SigletonClass sObj=[SigletonClass sharedSingletonClass];
   return [sObj valueForKey:InstVar];
}
```

**Function Calling:**

```
[self ReadSingleTonInstanceVariable:@"SomeInstanceVariableName"];
```

**NSString to int:**

```
-(int)ConvertToIntFromString:(NSString*)str
{
    return str.intValue;
}
```

As far as I’m aware, there are no performance issues with doing it one way over another.

I always prefer *singleton class* rather than *appdelegate* because the code will be clutter free and I consider overusing appdelegate as *smelly code*.

Comment: the show usage of the singleton is plain wrong. as this code does not enforce a singleton, several calls of `SigletonClass sObj=[[SigletonClass alloc]init];` will create new instances. Also the `sharedSingletonClass` method is using ancient code. Today most prefer `dispatch_once()`. calling `intValue` should be done after some sanity checks, as if it fails it will return 0 — you won't know if it is a valid number or if it failed.

Comment: Dear vikingosegundo,The concept of singleton is only one instance should exist.It's a design pattern it can be achieved using variety of ways.Doing it using GCD may be modern But the example I showed here is right.Please visit the below link to verify my answer. https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32.

Comment: Dear @H.duraiamuthan, and the concept of reputation on SO is that the 25K points I have should tell you, that I know, what the (anti-)pattern Singleton is. But the code you posted is plain wrong. it isn't a singleton. you are creating more than one SingletonClass if you call you `-ReadSingleTonInstanceVariable:` more than once. And please learn the naming convention for cocoa development.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Thanks for pointing out.Now I have corrected it.I misunderstood your first comment and pardon my naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

That breaks some patterns, I'd not use it.

Anyway, if you declare a property in your app delegate then you can call:
 `[[NSApp delegate] myVar]` anywhere.

How exactly do you intent to use this variable?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a singleton class to save all the variables which any class can access and scope is the entire runtime of the app.
Check out this [link](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/)