# How to define a global variable that can be accessed anywhere in my application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, variables, global

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Global int variable objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080661/global-int-variable-objective-c)

I would like to create a global variable.
I want to access to this variable anywhere.

The Java equivalent:

```
static var score:int = 0;
```

For example if I define a global variables into the Game class.
How to access to this global variable?

```
Game.score ?
```

Comment: The answer on the following link explains clearly http://stackoverflow.com/a/20423815/730807

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you are having multiple views in your application, and in that case you want to have a variable accessible to every view, you should always create a Model/Data class and define the variable in it. Something like this :

**Objective-C :**

```
//DataClass.h      
@interface DataClass : NSObject {    

    NSString *str;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *str;    
+(DataClass*)getInstance;    
@end  


//DataClass.m    
@implementation DataClass    
@synthesize str;

static DataClass *instance = nil;

+(DataClass *)getInstance
{    
    @synchronized(self)    
    {    
        if(instance==nil)    
        {    
            instance= [DataClass new];    
        }    
    }    
    return instance;    
}
```

Now in your view controller you need to call this method as :

```
DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];  
obj.str= @"I am Global variable";
```

This variable will be accessible to every view controller. You just have to create an instance of Data class.

**Swift :**

```
class DataClass {

    private var str: String!

    class var sharedManager: DataClass {
        struct Static {
            static let instance = DataClass()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }
}
```

Usage : `DataClass.sharedManager.str`

**Using `dispatch_once`**

```
class DataClass {

    private var str: String!

    class var sharedInstance: DataClass {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: DataClass? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = DataClass()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

Usage : `DataClass.sharedManager.str`

Comment: Should that line `return instance;` be inside the `@synchronized` block?

Comment: how would you get these variables in an NSManagedObject subclass where you can't edit the init method and it has no viewDidLoad to put it in?

Comment: dispatch_once() is most prefered for singleton..see the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20423815/730807

Comment: Wondereful. Workable, sweet and useful code!:)

Comment: Could this be considered as Singleton Pattern ?

Comment: I had problem with that .when i close application.this variable data become nil..any solution ???

Comment: Thanks Alot!, Btw, you have to use #import "DataClass.h" wherever you need to access the global variable.

Comment: Does this work for UIImages? I tried doing exactly what was posted for the NSString but I could not figure out how to get it to work with an image

Answer (score 20):

Objective-C does not have support for "class variables" directly. Instead, you can create a variable which is valid for the scope of the class's file and access it using class methods.

```
// outside the implementation
static int score = 0; // static means it is only accessible from the current file

@implementation Game

+ (int)score {
    return score;
}
+ (void)setScore:(int)newScore {
    score = newScore;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me getting rid of the warning `no static getter method named sharedInstance found return type default to id`

Comment: Simple and yet powerful

Comment: You made my weekend :)

Answer (score 7):

The preferred way to implement global variables in an iOS project (though these aren't true global variables), is to create a property in the application delegate, then just access that property from each of your classes.

---

**EDIT:** Re-reading your question, it looks like I misinterpreted your question, and ughoavgfhw's answer is probably what you're looking for. He's correct, there is no such thing as a class variable in Objective-C, so you have to create a regular C static variable, then create class methods (denoted by the `+` rather than a `-`) for setting and getting.

Though generally, when I need "global" variables in an app, I create singleton classes to house them and their related methods (so the app delegate doesn't overflow with unrelated properties), or if it's a smaller project I just use the application delegate (which is a also a singleton class) rather than separate singletons. Though there's nothing wrong with the static variable plus class setter/getter approach if that works better for your needs.

Comment: How does one access that property from other classes?

Comment: You can always get a reference to the app delegate like this: `(YourAppDelegateClass *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`. I put a #define macro in the app delegate header or use a class method so that I can access it in a cleaner way, but you don't have to.

Comment: Also, if you find yourself putting a lot of stuff in the app delegate, one, you should probably rethink your approach, but if it really is needed, you may want to consider creating a separate singleton class for this, or a regular class with a reference in your app delegate.

Comment: Thanks @einsteinx2! Yes exactly! I'm realizing now that I should have a model class in this app, but given that this is (hopefully) the last workaround I'll save that lesson for the next app.