# iphone how to pass string to another view label?

Tags: iphone, uiview, nsstring

My problem is how to pass string to another view label? I got try so many example but still can not get the value where I pass.

here is I save the data.

```
-(IBAction)Save:(id)sender{
    timedata = [datePicker date];
    NSLog(@"timedata save is = %@",timedata);

    time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timedata];

    NSLog(@"String time = %@",time);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

here is I want to show the save data.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    show = [[SelectDate alloc]initWithNibName:@"SelectDate" bundle:nil];
    show.time = time;
    NSLog(@"time = %@",time);

    Selectime.text = show.time;
    NSLog(@"show.time = %@",show.time);     

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set property for time in SelectDate viewController so that it can be accessed in other viewControllers.

//SelectDate.h

```
NSString *time;  
// Your declarations  
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *time;
```

//SelectDate.m

```
@synthesize time;
```

Now you can use time in other ViewControllers like you are doing.

Comment: i have add this oso.but still con not get the value.

Comment: You can use a Data class instead. Check out [My Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065965/how-to-define-a-global-variable-that-can-be-accessed-anywhere-in-my-application/6067515#6067515). Let me know if still you have problem.

Comment: Where my answer has started, you'll see a tick mark. Just tick it.

Answer (score 0):

To get a NSString representation of a date you should look at NSDateFormatter

example:

```
NSDate* timedata = [datePicker date];   
NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *time = [dateFormat timedata];
[dateFormat release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing last view, pass your data to your next view:

Hi,My problem is how to pass string to another view label? I got try so many example but still can not get the value where I pass.

here is I save the data.

```
-(IBAction)Save:(id)sender{
    timedata = [datePicker date];
    NSLog(@"timedata save is = %@",timedata);
    time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timedata];
    NSLog(@"String time = %@",time);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    YourNextView *yourNextView=[[YourNextView alloc] init];
    yourNextView.anString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timedata];
    [yourNextView release];
}
```

here is You want to show the save data.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    //show = [[SelectDate alloc]initWithNibName:@"SelectDate" bundle:nil];
    //show.time = time;
    //NSLog(@"time = %@",time);
    Selectime.text = self.anString;
    NSLog(@"show.time = %@",show.time); 
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```