# Global variables and objects in Objective C. What is the best way?

Tags: iphone, object, singleton, global-variables, extern

I want to use global variables and objects for the iphone project.

I have created NSobject class and defined like below:

**.h File:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobelClass : NSObject

extern NSString *mystr;

extern NSMutableArray *Arrdata;

@end
```

**.m File:**

```
#import "GlobelClass.h"

@implementation GlobelClass

NSString *mystr;
NSMutableArray *Arrdata;
@end
```

What is the best way Or should I use singleton pattern like below link answer:
[Using global variables in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604523/using-global-variables-in-objective-c)

Please share thoughts?

Comment: Are these constants? What are they used by? Why global?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to use global variable in the application is:

You can use App Delegate class itself :

.h file:

```
AppDelegate: UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

}

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* strUserID;
```

.m file:

```
@synthesize strUserID;
```

Now you can access strUserID as global variable in your UIViewController as:

```
ABCProjectAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ABCProjectAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

You can set value:

```
appDelegate.strUserID = @"Test";
```

Get Value:

```
NSString *strId = appDelegate.strUserID;
```

:)

Comment: The app delegate is for app level delegation of responsibility. Not a store of arbitrary code / constants / settings.

Comment: You can create one header file for the global variables. You can define global variables on that file. Is that approach you have thought before?