# Objective C Global Variable

Tags: objective-c, global-variables, extern

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here please.
I have created an NSobject called BeaconData. The header file is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface BeaconData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * jsonArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * bMajor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * bMinor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * bUUID;

-(void) getData;

@end
```

The implementation file is then:

```
#import "BeaconData.h"
#define getDataURL @"http://www.eventav.biz/websitebeacons/library/json/files/beacons.txt"

@implementation BeaconData

@synthesize jsonArray, bUUID, bMajor, bMinor;

//Retrieve data
-(void) getData
{
extern NSString * bUUID;
extern NSString * bMajor;
extern NSString * bMinor;

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

//Loop through Json Array
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    bUUID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"i_uuid"];
    bMajor = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"i_major"];
    bMinor = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"i_minor"];
 }    
}
@end
```

Next I try to call the Global variable bMajor in the main viewController.m file and print it out - just to see if it works, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

extern NSString * bMajor;

NSInteger beaconMajorInt = [bMajor integerValue];

NSLog (@"Beacon bMajor is %li", (long)beaconMajorInt);
```

But all I get is the following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_bMajor", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: It isn't global, why do you think it is / want it to be?

Comment: Why isn't it global? That is the question. If I just initialise the variable directly without the array - NSString * bMajor = @"47008"; like that - then it works.

Comment: It's not a global variable. It is a property whose value is specific to a given instance of a `BeaconData` object.

Comment: Ok - so how do I make it global. As I said, that is the question effectively. If I don't try to initialise it via an external data source ie using the array/dictionary, and just initialise it as NSString * bMajor = @"47008"; then it works fine??

Comment: @Mile just declare it above the implementation section.

Comment: @Chase - I've tried that too. Both in the BeaconData.m & viewController.m file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared your `bMajor` variable as a class property. This means that you must instantiate an instance of your `BeaconData` class to access the variable unless you include a class method.

However, in your code I see that you also want to make these variables global. It is redundant to declare a variable as a class property and then try to make it global. In objective-c simply declaring a variable outside the implementation section will make it global for all modules that import the file with the declaration. You do it like this:

```
NSString *bMajor = @"Your String";

@implementation BeaconData
// YOUR CLASS CODE
@end
```

You're using the `extern` keyword incorrectly. It should be used in .h  class files to let anything that imports it know that they have access to this variable. **You also must declare it like I showed in the .m class file**

.h looks like this:

```
extern NSString *bMajor;

@interface BeaconData : NSObject
@end
```

Just because you can do this doesn't mean you should. Based on your code I would suspect what you want to do is turn your `-getData` instance method into a class method for a singleton that allows the class to manage these "global" variables while keeping with good coding practice.

[This SO Q/A should provide you exactly what you need to create your singleton.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604523/using-global-variables-in-objective-c) I recommend you do it this way.

Then in your viewController you would access these variables by getting an instance of your class using the class method.

Comment: thank you. I had actually looked at the singleton approach but I thought that this way would be easier. I will revert to the singleton method. Thanks for the help :)