# Creating global Variables and Objects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I  am new to objective-C and working on an app in which there are multiple viewController Files. I need to access Value of variables set in one file to be accessible in other files. How can i implement this.

What i was doing that i created a class Globals.m and declared variables in it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Globals : NSObject

@property  NSString*  firstName;
@property NSString* lastName;
@property NSString* emailId;

@end
```

My question are:
1.will the above Declaration make these variables retain there values in  different files?

2. Where should i crete a object of this class which should be accessible
   in all files.

Comment: You can remove the @property annotation... (It's just for generating getter/setter methods.) Then, use #import to import this file wherever you want to use the variables.

Comment: after removing @property it is giving error cannot declare variable inside interface

Comment: I'd recommend having a look at a singleton pattern instead

Comment: Hmm, you know what? Just get rid of @interface (and @end). There is no need for annotations in this file because you're just declaring some constants.

Comment: @martinjakubik  I removed (@interface) and it dont gave error now. can u plz tell me that how can i create a global object

Comment: If you want an object (my answer does not create a class... just a flat file), then Popeye's answer is better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using global variables in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604523/using-global-variables-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

I'd maybe suggest using a Singleton pattern as it will allow you to hold an instance of the class through your app. So you could set `firstName` in one class and get it in another.

**MySingleton.h**

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject

// Our properties we want to set.
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *emailName;
// etc...

// Our class method for getting the shared instance.
+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

**MySingleton.m**

```
#import "MySingleton.h"

@implementation MySingleton

+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static id sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedObject;
}

@end
```

Then in your other classes all you need to do is import the `MySingleton` class and do something like :

```
MySingleton *singleton = [MySingleton sharedInstance];
[singleton setFirstName:@"Bob"];
```

For more information on Singleton Patterns and other Design Patterns here is a tutorial that you could read through [iOS Design Patterns](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns). Also a good read is [Correct Singleton Pattern Objective C (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598820/correct-singleton-pattern-objective-c-ios)

Comment: After this how can i access sharedObject in other files

Comment: See the edit I have just done. All you need to do is call the class method something like `MySingleton *singleton = [MySingleton sharedInstance];` and then you can access all the properties it has.

Comment: variables when accessed in different in different files will retain there value??

Comment: @Popeye you still need #import, no? (Assuming your classes are in different files...)

Comment: @martinjakubik Yes sorry I'll update with that but I normally assume imports are a given.

Comment: @JuniorBillgates Yes they will retain there values.

Comment: @Popeye yes, I see. It's up to you... It's just that this question is about such a basic mechanism that maybe it warrants showing the whole file in the examples.