# Is there any way to declare a global variable in app that can be accessed thorough out app?

Tags: objective-c

- I have tried to declare a var in .pch file but it gives error of undeclared identifier at the place it used. Am I missing some thing or is there any other way to use global vars.
- I don't want to create a separate class for that.
- A global var shouldn't be constant (i.e. that should be get and set)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.[image: My .pch file[![][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odKio.png)

Comment: Make it as property of AppDelegate.

Comment: This has been asked several times. A good answer is to be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080661/global-int-variable-objective-c/20423815#20423815

Comment: When you tried in .pch file did you type "static" in its declaration?

Comment: Never declare a variable in the .pch.  Never touch the .pch, if you can help it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouly use a Singleton for a globally accessible value.